# Related to payments made by accountant to vendors

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, verbs, sentence-choice

Vendor To recipient : Hello I'm here to receive the payment for the goods rendered to your store. Could you please let me know who pays for it Or  Should it be "Who does the payment for the obligations?"

Now what should recipient be replying?

X does the payment? Or X pays for the obligations Or what else?

Comment: "Could you please tell me who [handles / is responsible for] payments to suppliers?" Obligation means واجِب not دَيْن

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are idiomatic or likely from a fluent speaker in AmE.

> Hello I'm here to receive the payment for the goods rendered to your store. Could you please let me know who pays for it?

sounds stilted and awkward to me. The phrase "goods rendered", while not incorrect, would in my view be unlikely to be used in such a connection, it sounds more like legalese re-used out of context. "receive the payment" is also unlikely, although not incorrect.

The given alternative:

> Who does the payment for the obligations?

also seems awkward. One does not normally speak of "doing" a payment,. but rather of "making a payment", and it would be unusual (although again not incorrect) to speak of "obligation" in this context.  Again this sounds like someone who picked up phrases of legalese and is using them in a less formal context where the phrases do not work well. Both examples sound over-formal to me.

I would express this idea as something like one of:

> - Hello, I am here to collect for the goods delivered to your store from {vendor}. Who takes care of such payments?
> - Hello, I am here to collect for the delivery  from {vendor}. Who takes care of paying that?

Either of those woudl be much more natural (in AmE), in my view.